# Group every n-th element of array

Tags: arrays, ruby, grouping

I have an array:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How do I group every n-elements of array? For example, for 3:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

I wrote this code, but it's ugly:

```
array.each_with_index.group_by { |e, i| i % 3}.map {|h| h[1].map { |e| e[0] }}
```

Comment: @Makyen come on lets help the poor guy out

Comment: @MohitBhasi, We are not here to do someone's homework for them. Help them, yes.  Do it for them, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nick Veys' answer is most straightforward, but here is another way.

```
array.group_by.with_index{|_, i| i % 3}.values
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: It's better, because @NickVeys solution didn't work when: 1) We have array length less than number of groups (in example it's 3) 2) We have error when modulo isn't 0 at dividing array length to number of groups

Answer (score 9):

Here's an easy way:

```
array.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way out:

```
irb(main):002:0> a =  Array(1..9)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):004:0> a.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose # good
=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

*Not what you want? Let me know*

Comment: Wouldn't that just put out `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done by creating a hash, then extracting the values. For Ruby 1.9+, this would preserve the order of the elements of the array.

**Code**

```
def bunch(arr,ngroups)
  arr.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |(e,i),h|
       h[i%ngroups] << e }
     .values
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

bunch(arr,1) #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] 
bunch(arr,2) #=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]] 
bunch(arr,3) #=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]] 
bunch(arr,4) #=> [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]] 
bunch(arr,5) #=> [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5]] 
bunch(arr,6) #=> [[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9], [4], [5], [6]] 
bunch(arr,7) #=> [[1, 8], [2, 9], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]] 
bunch(arr,8) #=> [[1, 9], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]] 
bunch(arr,9) #=> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

**Alternatives**

If the argument were instead the size of each group, `grp_size`, we could compute:

```
ngroups = (arr.size+grp_size-1)/grp_size
```

The operative line of the method could instead be written:

```
arr.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(e,i),h| (h[i%ngroups] ||= []) << e }
   .values
```